# cURL error for cron

Tags: server, curl

I have this error which causes me a lot of trouble with all of my crons for some of my website :

> cURL error 28: connect() timed out!

The websites are stored on a shared servers i guess, how can I fix it ? Can't find something to help me on this point anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is most often related to the server configuration!

Contact your hosting company and ask the hosting support to check the following points:

- The server is running a recent version of PHP and the cURL library.
- Increase PHP Memory Limit settings.
- Ask your web host if there is some limitation with wp-cron, or if loopback is disabled.
- Ask your WebHost if there a firewall or security module (e.g. mod_security ) that could block outgoing cURL requests.
- Your hosting company might need to switch DNS configuration to something like OpenDNS.

Comment: I've ended up with increasing to 512M my memory limit, but sometime still not enough, but yes, this is clearly a server config. thx